# javascript jquery plugin clashes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, plugins

A simple gallery works fine with:

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.1.min.js and

But when I add the following for a "quicksand" filter the gallery stops working:

Could there be an easy fix without trawling through all the code to find clashes? Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at [`.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/).

Answer (score 1):

You are including jQuery twice. One time by hand, and one time via the zabb.co.uk URL. For the 'quicksand' plugin find a file that doesn't include jQuery but only the plugin.

It's even in the HTML source:

```
<!-- DO NOT USE THESE FILES. they are compiled for fast http access -->
<!-- if you’re looking for source, download or read documentation -->
```

So grab them from the GitHub repo for quicksand.

Comment: Oh, come on... if we were the type of people who read directions, we wouldn't be programmers.